# how does one validate the "." in e-mail addresses?

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I have the following method to validate my e-mail addresses in a form.

```
 -(BOOL) validEmailAddress:(NSString*) emailString {
    NSString *regExPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:emailString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [emailString length])];
    if (regExMatches == 0) 
        return NO; // email invalid
     else
        return YES; // email valid 
  }
```

This works great except that it breaks down if the user gives an e-mail of "abc@xyz" (without a super domain like .com or .org).

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the "." in my regex. I tried escaping it like this,

```
NSString *regExPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
```

but that doesn't work, either. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I didn't put in the escape before the last dot when originally posting the question. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean *breaks down*? Does your function consider `abc@xyz` a valid e-mail address? If so, that's good, because `abc@xyz` *is* a valid e-mail address.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for some other hints about validating an email with regular expressions

Comment: and http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt for a list of valid Top Level Domains

Comment: @Oswald, Yes - that is what I meant. Do you mean to say that an e-mail address without a superdomain like .com and the like is valid?

Comment: @Justin-NicholasY.Toyama: Validation of email addresses is not something that you just pull out of the air.  It's also a topic that is discussed almost daily.  Please search for "email address validation" here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AndyLester, I agree. The real work happens on the server. Even though this is not very exhaustive, having something on the iPhone side that can take care of some simple validation saves server calls and the user can skip several seconds from the whole transaction if we catch it before the server call is made. Don't you think?

Comment: I did not say that email address validation is not worth doing.  I am saying that it is a well-discussed topic and there are many threads on Stack Overflow discussing it with much written, debugged and tested code out there for you to use rather than wasting your time to write your own from scratch.

Comment: @Justin-NicholasY.Toyama An e-mail address without a second level domain is indeed possible. You have distinguish two aspects: 1) Is the e-mail address syntactically valid. This is harder than it look and I have seen regular expressions that fill a whole page. 2) Is an inbox associated with an e-mail address. This cannot be done without sending an e-mail and hoping that the recieving server is nice enough to send a bounce if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an escape sequence in your last example.  Try:

```
NSString *regExPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
```

Comment: I tried this with a single backslash and it doesn't work, plus the compiler complains it's not a recognized escape sequence. So you have to escape the dot and escape the backslash??? I'm trying it now.

Comment: @Justin-NicholasY.Toyama Yeah, that's a strange quirk of regular expressions. Since \ is a character that you might want to include in your regex, you have to double it to indicate that it's an escape sequence.  \. means "a slash followed by any character" (because . is a wildcard), while \\. means a literal dot.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. Your solution is satisfactory for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the last dot. Your expression is therefore the following:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

However, since the `\` is also interpreted as escape character by Objective C, you will have to escape it. This is done in Objective C by using the double backslash (`\\`)

```
NSString *regExPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
```

Comment: I tried this. This doesn't work. Bill the Lizard's code works, although I don't know why.

Comment: The actual regular expression has only one backslash. However the `\ ` is also interpreted as escape char in Objective C and needs to be escaped there as well making you end up with 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the dot, yes.

To accept "abc@xyz", you'll also need to make the dot and everything after it optional.  You can do this by encapsulating it in parentheses and following it with a question mark, like:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+(\.[A-Z]{2,4})?$
```

Comment: If @Oswald's comment is right, then this is a good implementation if it works. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin-NicholasY.Toyama Just to add a bit more complexity, if you are trying to accept ANY valid e-mail address, this is nowhere near exhaustive, as seen in Wikipedia's [examples of valid e-mail addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses)